# Cookies in Apache HTTP Client - Java

Tags: java, apache, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm having kind of a problem with the Apache httpclient for Java. I'm writing a login bot for a website, which extracts all the fields from the login forms, fills in username and password and logs into the account by making a POST request. I tried it using the classes provided by java, but there I got thrown back to the login page every time. 
It seems to work with the Apache client, but I tried to remove all the cookie handling code to see if it still works. I no longer save cookies in a list and I don't add cookies to the request, but it seems that I'm still getting logged in correctly. How can that be? I don't use a cookiestore and I don't know where the cookies are coming from, so obviously they must be saved somewhere in the background. I need to clear them to start a new session.
I create the client like this

```
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

and make requests like this

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url+"/login");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 2):

My English is poor.
The cookies are actually coming from CookieStore.But the cookies aren't operated in execute(HttpUriRequest request).
If you want add or remove cookies.you can use execute(HttpUriRequest request, HttpContext context) .
eg:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by y.wang on 11/16/16.
 */
public class HttpClientTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpClientContext httpClientContext = new HttpClientContext();
        String url = "";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url + "/login");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post, httpClientContext);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpClientContext.getCookieStore().clear();
    }
}
```